# Filtering message on basis of logical ports BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I am working on a BizTalk application where multiple orchestrations send and receive messages to and from message box. I am in a situation where I need to put a filter in a receive shape and filter on basis of a direct port.

My original question is can filters be made on direct ports?

What I am basically trying to do is suppose the message was deposited into message box by a direct port `dp1`, in a receive shape I want to filter and receive the message only if the message was deposited by `dp1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean a Direct bound Orchestration Port, then you can use the **BTS.Operation** Context Property which is Promoted when the message is published to the MessageBox.

It gets it's value from the Operation Name property.

Comment: Or you could promote a property in the message that you publish to use for routing.  That would be better from a SOA approach.